# Install a language with ASDF through Ansible on Debian

Tags: linux, bash, debian, ansible

I'd like to write playbooks to install my development environment. Most steps went well, but I'm struggling to install Ruby through `asdf`.

Playbooks are splitted and called from a `main.yaml`. The one installing `asdf` works fine:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Detects previous installations of asdf
      command: asdf version > /dev/null
      register: asdf_check
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: Download and install asdf
      block:
        - name: Clone asdf repository into ~/.asdf
          ansible.builtin.git:
            name: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git
            dest: ~/.asdf
            single_branch: yes
            version: v0.14.0

        - name: Insert lines to ~/.bashrc to source asdf
          ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
            path: "/home/{{ unix_username }}/.bashrc"
            block: |
              . "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"
              . "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"

        # Note for superuser post:
        #  I'm not sure to keep this, I added it to try a specific approach described below
        - name: Set execution permissions to asdf.sh (reset later on)
          ansible.builtin.file:
            path: "/home/{{ unix_username }}/.asdf/asdf.sh"
            mode: "744"
            owner: "{{ unix_username }}"
            group: "{{ unix_username }}"
      when: asdf_check.rc > 0
```

But none of the approach I tried successfully installed Ruby latest version. I tried:

- sourcing `~/.bashrc` before calling `asdf`
- using `asdf` absolute path
- using `bash -lc`
- using `ansible.builtin.command`
- using `ansible.builtin.shell`

**Using `ansible.builtin.command`, `bash -lc` and `asdf` absolute path:** task marked as "changed", but does not install anything

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Install asdf ruby plugin
      ansible.builtin.command: "bash -lc '/home/{{ unix_username }}/.asdf/asdf.sh plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git'"

    # Other tasks install Ruby latest and register it globally using the same approach
```

**Using `ansible.builtin.command`, `bash -lc` and `source .bashrc`:** rc127, `asdf: command not found`

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Install asdf ruby plugin
      ansible.builtin.command: "bash -lc 'source /home/{{ unix_username }}/.bashrc && asdf plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git'"

    # Other tasks install Ruby latest and register it globally using the same approach
```

**Using `ansible.builtin.shell` and `asdf` absolute path:** rc127, `asdf: command not found`

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Install asdf ruby plugin
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        executable: /bin/bash
        cmd: "/home/{{ unix_username }}/.asdf/asdf.sh plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git"

    # Other tasks install Ruby latest and register it globally using the same approach
```

**Using `ansible.builtin.shell` and `source .bashrc`:** rc127, `asdf: command not found`

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Install asdf ruby plugin
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        executable: /bin/bash
        cmd: "source /home/{{ unix_username }}/.bashrc && asdf plugin add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git"

    # Other tasks install Ruby latest and register it globally using the same approach
```

---

Beyond finding a working solution for this task, could you explain why all those approaches failed ?